# python-paramiko rpm has been deprecated in RHEL 7, is there any alternative for this?

Tags: python, rhel

I have to support some of the RHEL 6 developed scripts with RHEL 7 as well, but while installing the rpm for the features I am getting an error due to import paramiko in some of my feature scripts. I surfed for the error and found that RHEL has removed their support for python-paramiko. Can there be any alternative to this paramiko rpm?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely yes. You can either use a RPM repository which provides python-paramiko, or you can install paramiko from the Python package repository.

## use a RPM repository

You can get `python-paramiko-2.1.1-2.el7` from the `rhel-7-server-extras-rpms` repository. Enable that repository by running

```
sudo subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
```

## install paramiko from pypi.python.org

First, install the Python 2.7 Software Collection, see https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/python27/

```
sudo subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
sudo yum install python27
scl enable python27 bash
```

now install paramiko

```
pip install --user paramiko
```

you should probably create a Python virtual environment, see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv